# 2017 Intel 4K iMac, broken FileVault decryption

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption, filevault

macOS Monterey on a 2017 4k Intel iMac. Another person has reported it on their 2017 MBP where FileVault was enabled intentionally but then turned off.

A week ago I turned FileVault on by mistake, so after it finished encrypting the drive I went straight to decrypt it.
Then I assume that near the end of the decryption, it went auto update and rebooted itself.

Now I can't get into system. I'm now into a dead loop of `Reboot->Enter password->"Your computer has restarted because of a problem"->Reboot`.
So I'm now in Recovery Mode.

Things I have checked (using Terminal):

- The drive is shown in Disk Utility as APFS(Encrypted), can be mounted and can read and write
- `diskutil apfs list`: The drive `disk4s1` (Macintosh HD - Data), `Decryption progress: 99.0% (Paused) (Unlocked)`, `Encrypted: No`
- `diskutil cs list`: `No CoreStorage logical volume groups found`
- `diskutil apfs disableFileVault disk4s1 -user F0A57C09-753C-46BB-AD66-EC07CBF03DEB`: `Error starting decryption of APFS Volume: The given APFS Volume is already encrypting or decrypting (-69573)`[1]
- `diskutil apfs unlockVolume disk4s1`: `The APFS Volume disk4s1 is already unlocked (mounted)`
- `/usr/libexec/corestoraged`: Running or sleeping. `diskutil apfs list` still shown as `Paused`.

[1] The UUID is from `diskutil apfs listUsers disk4s1`.

---

Now I see it's stuck in 99.0%, is there a command to continue the decryption progress?

Or the worst, is the only way to save my data is to copy all files to an external drive and do a wipe?

Comment: Just to confirm: Without Recovery, you’re able to log in to your user account and briefly see the panic report panel, before the system automatically reboots on you, correct? Have you tried booting into Safe Mode?

Comment: @pion Sorry I should have write this. No I can't get into the system. I was able to enter my password, saw progress bar move to middle, and crash.